# Uncaught Error: No template specified for component MyApp

Tags: templates, ionic2, components

I am trying to update my ionic 2 Beta 2 code to ionic 2 RC0 and am getting a No template specified error in my app.component.ts file.

The relevant part of the app.component.ts file looks like this:

```js
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html',
})

export class MyApp {
    rootPage: any = HomePage;
    loggedIn:boolean = false;

    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

    root: any;// = HomePage;


    constructor() {
        ...
    }
}
```

According to the update instructions for updating an app to release candidate 0 for ionic 2 the app.html file is in the same directory as the app.component.ts file and the path is `app.html`

When running the ionic app both Firefox and Chrome complain that no template has been specified for app.component.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had the same problem and what was causing was a commented line. I suggest that answer even if you didn't include a commented line in your example (I supposed that you didn't imagine that a commented line could cause the error). The following produced the same error as you :

```
@Component({
    //template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`  
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
```

I had to do the following change for the compilation to work (while using [ionic-app-scripts](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/) @ 0.0.30, I have the feeling that the problem appeard between v0.0.23 and v0.0.30, but I didn't investigate) :

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
  //template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
```

Comment: Thanks, how in the world did you figure it out? so it only appears in Ionic right? - Angular apps are not affected by this?

Comment: I solved the problem by chance but it took me one or two hours to figure it out :-).
I don't know if there is a similar problem with Angular 2 apps because I only tested Ionic 2 apps. As I suppose that the problem comes from ionic-app-script, I can only suggest to keep it updated. The Ionic team improved it a lot the past weeks but I havn't had the chance to test it to check if the problem is still there.

Comment: The same bug exists in Angular 2, removing the comment cleared the error.

Comment: 2018 March 28th, I just run into this :( bug, and I am using ionic 3, I was chasing for 3 hours why my page specific context menus buttons where not showing up in this one project. Guess what I was using a template: so I comment it out and voila I hit another 4 hours nightmare bug .

Answer (score 3):

In layman terms, in your component.ts file add templateURL. Follow the code snippet as follows :-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-securelogin-receiver',
  templateUrl: './securelogin-receiver.component.html',
  providers: [SecureloginService]
})
```

Which is being referred at the time of component load, hence its unavailability throws exception.

> Error: No template specified for component
>   SecureloginReceiverComponent

above exception i got in templateURL's absence.